# How to update Eclipse Marketplace credentials?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using eclipse neon and I would like to install some plug-ins I have added to my favorites with my eclipse account in the browser. When I access the eclipse marketplace in the IDE and select favorites tab I get the below error:

```
Login failed: Not Acceptable: Account is temporarily blocked.
```

I've tried reinstalling eclipse, deleting everything in the installation directory and workspace. I had eclipse previously installed on this PC and have recently changed my password so I'm guessing the old credentials are still stored somewhere, but I can't find out where.

Comment: You don't _need_ credentials to download plugins. I can search the marketplace and install what I need, it is just more convenient to have access to your favorite plugins in a list, but I can't sign in.

Comment: Nevermind then, I didn't know about this :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was a temporary issue with the eclipse marketplace, as today I was simply prompted to enter my credentials instead of facing the error.